# Issue with substring and Vector.add

Tags: java, string, vector, javafx-2

Code:

```
private static Vector<String> storage = new Vector<>();

//Message -> Vector
private static void convertToVector(String string) {
    String msg = string;

    int tempInt = 0;

    while (msg.length() > 1) {
        int run = 0;

        if (msg.indexOf('[') >= 0 && msg.indexOf(']') > 0 && msg.indexOf(':') >= 0) {
            storage.add(msg.substring(msg.indexOf('[')+1, msg.indexOf(':')));
        }

        if (msg.indexOf(':') > 0 && msg.indexOf(']') > 0) {
            tempInt = msg.indexOf("][#");
            if (tempInt < 1)
                tempInt = msg.length()-1;   
            storage.add(msg.substring(msg.indexOf(':')+1, tempInt));
        }

        if (msg.length() > tempInt) {
            msg = msg.substring(tempInt+1);
            run = 1;
        }

        if (msg.length() == tempInt || run == 0)
            msg = "";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < storage.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(storage.get(i));
    }
}
```

Case 1 msg = [#userInfo#:xyz] <-- working

```
    #userInfo#
    xyz
```

Case 2 msg = [#userInfo#:xyz][#userInfo#:xy] <-- not working?

```
    #userInfo#
    xyz
```

Case 3 msg = [#userInfo#:xyz][#userInfo#:xy][#userInfo#:gfdgfd] <-- working

```
    #userInfo#
    xyz
    #userInfo#
    xy
    #userInfo#
    gfdgfd
```

Can anyone explain why case2 is not working, it only happens when the last username equals the previous minus last letter.

Comment: What is your code supposed to accomplish?

Comment: And where is the code that prints that output?

Comment: @svasa added the Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want to change your last check to just:

```
        if (msg.length() > tempInt) {
            msg = msg.substring(tempInt + 1);
        } else {
            msg = "";
        }
```

and get rid of the run variable.

As is, in case 2, the message length is checked against tempInt after the message has already been modified to remove the initial match, and coincidentally has tempInt characters left.

I think you're just trying to stop when you fail a match or hit the end of the string, so the "else" should be fine, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for what reason you have this :

```
if (msg.length() == tempInt || run == 0) msg = "";
```

In the second case, this is true and you are exiting out of loop because your while condition is `msg.length() > 1`.

Comment out that line and see that it gives you desired output.